# How to get text in a button's label to conform to Grid and GridRow?

Tags: button, swiftui, grid

When I iterate through a table of data and present the contents using `GridRow` inside a `Grid`, everything aligns as I expect it to.

```
VStack {
    Text(table.name)
    Grid {
        ForEach(currents) { current in
           GridRow {
               Text(current.type)
                   .gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
               Text(current.time)
                   .gridColumnAlignment(.center)
               Text(current.speed)
                   .gridColumnAlignment(.center)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

But when I try to make each row a clickable button by placing each row inside a `label` it no longer seems to be aware of the spacing set up by the previous `GridRow`

```
VStack {
    Text(table.name)
    Grid {
        ForEach(currents) { current in
            Button {
                selectedCurrent = current
                // do something
            } label: {
                GridRow {
                    Text(current.type)
                        .gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
                    Text(current.time)
                        .gridColumnAlignment(.center)
                    Text(current.speed)
                        .gridColumnAlignment(.center)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

How to I maintain the integrity of the `Grid` `GridRow` spacing while making each row a clickable button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this alternative way: add `tapGesture` on each row and set the `foregroundColor` blue to make it visually tappable.

```swift
VStack {
    Text(table.name)
    Grid {
        ForEach(currents) { current in
            GridRow {
                Text(current.type)
                    .gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
                Text(current.time)
                    .gridColumnAlignment(.center)
                Text(current.speed)
                    .gridColumnAlignment(.center)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .onTapGesture {   
                selectedCurrent = current
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked fine. I was too focused on solving it with one method, I didn't consider others.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it had limitations with built-in components.